# Android java, error during import of string from string.xml with getString()

Tags: java, android, xml, object, nullpointerexception

i have a problem.
I'm creating an application that stores data in the cell , but first create a folder that will contain the various files . This folder will have the name of the app, but continuoa receive an error at that point.

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f060014

The class is:

```
public class Config {

private Properties configuration;
public static String root = Resources.getSystem().getString((R.string.app_name)) + "_data_file";
public File cartella = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/obb/"+ root);
private String configurationFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/obb/"+ root  + "/config.ini";
```

and String.xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Il Maestro</string>
    <string name="homefrontextb">Per iniziare,completa il modulo.</string>
    <string name="homefrontext">Per iniziare,seleziona la tua lingua.</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="sondaggiopub">Come hai conosciuto quest\' app?</string>
    <string name="Pubblicita">Pubblicità</string>
    <string name="socialnetwork">Social Network</string>
    <string name="amici">Consigliata dagli amici</string>
    <string name="store">Visita casuale sullo store</string>
    <string name="namehome">Nome</string>
    <string name="cognomehome">Cognome</string>
    <string name="nickhome">Nickname</string>
    <string name="emailhome">Email</string>
</resources>
```

However , when I try to get the string as int , it works , and I get the number " 2131099668 "

Please help me , I'm going crazy ..

Comment: Try Change from Resources.getSystem() to getResources().

Answer (score 1):

`Resources.getSystem()` retrieves the System's resources, not the one specific of your app. From the doc

> Return a global shared Resources object that provides access to only
>   system resources (no application resources), and is not configured for
>   the current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based
>   on orientation, etc).

You need your app's context to access your specific resources

Comment: Write a code example, I can not understand what you mean.

Comment: I have resolved... Thanks you so much!!! it have declared a function with context and called method in a main!!! Thank you,you saved my life hahaha